# How to generate a cloud formation template in YML/JSON file with an already exists Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have an already EC2 instance is there any way to get the cloud formation template of it.I already try Launch template but unable to get the yml or json file from this can any one help this I am new to cloud formation template.

Answer (score 0):

You have the CloudFormer beta version in CloudFormation.

[CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)

I hope you just want the part of the AWS architecture, and not the EC2 operating system ''information''. For that the easiest way is create a image from the ec2, and load that in the cloud formation template after export using cloudformer.